# the sum of ascending powers of a prime can not equal the sum of ascending powers of a different prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was thinking about a question that I can't prove and can't find any proof/counter example for so here it is:

prove the equation:
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^x p_1^i = \sum\limits_{i=o}^y p_2^i
$$ 
has no solutions where $p_1 $ and $p_2$ are distinct primes and x and y are arbitrary constants.

Comment: Based on the answer, I think you should qualify the statement with $p_1$ and $p_2$ both greater than 2.

Comment: okay, anybody got any suggestions for primes greater than 2?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that $1+5+25=1+2+4+8+16$.

Comment: Seems to be the only solution up to $10^6$.